# Check Normal distribution with Kolmogorov test

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, statistics

I am a learning statistics using python, and I have a task to check that data have Normal Distribution with mean=10 and dispersion=5.5. 
I've checked scipy.stats.kstest function, but I don't understand how to interpret the results, and where I should pass mean and dispersion args.

Thank you, for your help

Comment: Where is the data? And what code have you written so far?

Comment: Data is large and it's is reading from file from test file, in the file about 1000 float numbers. About code it's whole task, read file and check normal distribution, I've loaded data from file and sort it by ascending order

Comment: @OlegZdanevich please have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generate a dataset

```
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
# generate data with norm(mean = 0,std = 15)
data = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(loc = 0,scale = 15,size = 1000,random_state = 0)
```

## Perfrom KS-test

```
# perform KS test on your sample versus norm(10,5.5)
D, p = scipy.stats.kstest(data, 'norm', args= (10, 5.5))
test = 'Reject' if p < 0.05 else 'Not reject'
print(f'D-statistics: {D:.4f},\np-value: {p:.4f}, \ntest-result: {test}')
```

Out:

> 'D-statistics:0.5091,p-value:0.0000,test-result:Reject'

## Add a plot with distributions and your data

```
# draw a plot to see the distribution and your data hist
# draw a plot to see the distribution and your data hist
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
x = np.linspace(data.min(),data.max(),100)
ax.plot(x, scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,loc = 10, scale = 5.5), 'r-', color='green', lw=1, alpha=0.6, label='norm(10,5.5) pdf')
ax.hist(data, normed=True, histtype='stepfilled', bins=20, alpha=0.2, label='my data distribution')
ax.legend(loc='best', frameon=False)
plt.title('norm(10,5.5) vs. data')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

if error occured，‘Polygon’ object has no property ‘normed’

it was found，normed=True , this property is deprecated，

change to use 'density=True'.

it will work.